# Javascript loop - create variable name

Tags: javascript

this javascript code loads a csv file from my server and creates a variable.

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
var zpetne = 5;

    function load() {
      for (var y = month - zpetne; y < month; y++) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'LINK_TO_SITE/CSV_FILES'+ y +'-17.csv',
          dataType: 'text',
        }).done(systemCZ);

        function systemCZ(data) {
          window.aktivitaData = data;
        }
      }
    }
```

The problem is that each runing of loop overrides previous data in aktivitaData. I tried edit my variable to

```
window.aktivitaData + y = data;
```

But it not works. I can't find any solution to get aktivitaData1, aktivitaData2 and so on. How can I declare variable like that?

Comment: make it an array and push each loop value onto the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array to keep track on the history of data. you can use `.push()` to add it into the array and access the data by index like `aktivitaData[0]` for the first data like below

```js
var aktivitaData = []; //first intialize it as empty
var dateObj = new Date();
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
var zpetne = 5;

function load() {
  for (var y = month - zpetne; y < month; y++) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'LINK_TO_SITE/CSV_FILES' + y + '-17.csv',
      dataType: 'text',
    }).done(systemCZ);

    function systemCZ(data) {
      window.aktivitaData.push(data);
    }
  }
}

function printAll() {
  for (var i = 0; i < window.aktivitaData.length; i++)
    console.log(window.aktivitaData[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `window` is an object, you can create dynamic properties like this:

```
var propertyName = 'aktivitaData' + y;
window[propertyName] = data;
```

assuming `y` is `test` you can access `data` like `aktivitaDatatest`.